# Centering Issues

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a long line of text. Instead of all being on the same line, it's separating over two lines.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="head">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p><a href="#">Last.fm</a> / <a href="#">Twitter</a> / <a href="#">Dribbble</a> / <a href="#">GitHub</a></p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#head{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 760px;
 text-align: center;
}

#head p{
 line-height: 1em;
 margin: 0;
}
```

And I get this result:

[image]

I feel obscenely dumb. There's probably an easy answer to this, but I can't wrap my head around it. Help?

Comment: Can you provide a link? I'm not seeing that effect when I try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rz48M/

Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I put it here: http://ethan.luffle.com/labs/ethan/

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I inserted an extra `</p>`. Doh!

Thanks for your time, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your `<p>` tag

Are you sure there's no other CSS affecting the relevant elements? (e.g. check in FireBug).

Try placing `!important` after your `#head` width to see if this corrects things. If so then you have a cascading issue that you need to resolve.

Comment: Oops. I had just copied it over quickly and forgot the closing tag.

Comment: `!important` did not work. I checked in Firebug and nothing was affecting it besides the font styles. Link to the whole page: http://ethan.luffle.com/labs/ethan

Answer (score 0):

It's going automatically to wrap at white space when the `p` tag is not large enough to contain all the text on one line. It would appear that you should have enough `width` based on your styles, but without seeing the page, it's tough to know.

You could add `white-space: no-wrap;` to your `#head p` styles or insert `&nbsp;` between your links.

Post a link if you can as it seems what you have should work.

Comment: `white-space: no-wrap;` didn't work. Neither did `&nbsp;` between them. Link to the whole page: http://ethan.luffle.com/labs/ethan

Comment: You're wrapping each set of links in a `p` tag. That is causing the wrapping. You just want a single `p` tag if you want all the links on 1 line. A more appropriate way to build this navigation would be a `ul`